# Can Azure AD Guest user perform software installtion?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

Can Azure AD Guest user perform software installation, configurations and verification on a server? If yes, what role they should be assigned to perform these task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Local administrator rights on Windows devices aren't applicable to Azure AD B2B guest users. Azure AD guest (B2B) accounts are not supported for Windows logon.

Guest users can be external users not in Azure AD at all. In order to even sign in to a virtual machine which is joined to Azure AD domain services. you need NTLM password hashes to be available for these users. Since the passwords for these guest users are not stored within the same tenant, they will not be able to sign in and therefore won't be able to be elevated to an admin role. This is by design.

Additional reading: [Assign local admin rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/assign-local-admin#:%7E:text=Local%20administrator%20rights%20on%20Windows,%2C%20changes%20aren%27t%20instant.)